# Statsmodels 0.5.0, having trouble with TAB completion in IPython

Tags: python, autocomplete, tab-completion, statsmodels

Simple, but really frustrating problem - TAB completion doesn't work with statsmodels package. I've tried different methods of installation (.exe or via pip; easy_install won't work), but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what this question means. What have you done so far? What do you expect to happen? I'm going to go out on a limb and say that maybe you got the import wrong. It should be

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```